# Проблемы с запуском приложения React-native

Tags: react-native

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу запустить приложение react-native. Когда пытаюсь запустить выскакивает ошибка: The expected package.json path: E:\native\package.json does not exist. Пробую запускать через npm start и expo start, но не запускается. Вот мое содержимое файла package.json. В чем моя ошибка??? Спасибо и добра вам

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"eject": "expo eject"
},
"dependencies": {
"expo": "~41.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите папку node modules и файлы с расширением .lock. Затем npm install and expo start -c

Comment: ,Спасибо, но не получилось. Сначала удалил папку с файлами, потом прописал команду вашу. Но мне опять установилась папка node modules, а запустить не удается(((

Comment: Если бы была внутренняя ошибка в package.json, вы б не смогли установить node modules.
У вас новый проект? вы запускаете команду в папке в которой лежит package.json?

Comment: да, у меня новый проект. Я пишу expo start в файле App.js в папке вместе с package.json

Comment: Открой в webstorm package.json и слева от expo start нажми на зеленую кнопку "RUN"